# Rails App [3.2.14] seems to be connecting to wrong database? [mysql]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've created a simple app that pulls some info from a remote database... everything is working fine on my development station with both ENV=production & ENV=development (the database server is in my LAN, as well as the production web server).

When I go to put my app into production on the production server ( apache + phusion passenger) I get the "We're sorry but something went wrong" notice.  Looking into my production.log shows the error responsible for ruining my day:

> Started GET "/" for 76.*.* at 2013-09-30 14:38:08 -0700
>
> Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'176.16.2.100' (using password: YES)):

My database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: parts
  pool: 5
  host: 192.168.1.200
  port: 3306
  username: xxx
  password: xxxx

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: parts
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  port: 3306
  host: 192.168.1.200
  user: xxx
  password: xxxx
```

Dropping into rails console yields the correct functionality (querying the 'parts' database works just fine) but as soon as I try to access the app from the web it tries to connect() to the wrong database?  Any help/suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: scyllinice on efnet was kind enough to point out that 'user' was supposed to be 'username'... fixed my problem

Comment: Make it as closed if you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the keyword user for production. Also, I am not happy to see the real IP address and username in your post. You should be more secretive when you ask a question for your client's sake.

Comment: Yeah I caught the user line shortly after posting... I stripped out the only real IP (76...) the other two are my internal LAN IP's (192.x LAN / 176.x LAN DMZ).  And there is no "client" -- this was an in house project for my own business, written by myself.